# How to clone a repository that needs SSO in GitHub Desktop?

Tags: github, github-desktop

I am trying to clone a repository. It needs SSO to view it. I use a Personal Access Token(with repo permission) for push, pull, etc.

Now I am trying to use GitHub Desktop, but it says authentication failed when I'm trying to clone the repository. Entering the correct credentials is throwing the same error.

[image]

How can I clone this repository and use it in GitHub Desktop?

PS: Other repositories(that don't need SSO) are cloning fine.

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to Preferences -> accounts and sign in there. What helped in my case was to sign out and sign in again using the option to sign in with browser.

Also this documentation was helpful : https://docs.github.com/en/desktop/installing-and-configuring-github-desktop/installing-and-authenticating-to-github-desktop/authenticating-to-github

Comment: This worked for me. All I did was sign out, do the sign in via browser, and then it worked.